# Broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER Intent issue

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics, broadcastreceiver, google-play

My Android Manifest file

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
      <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

I don't have any other receiver.

Test:

```
 ~/development/sdk/platform-tools $ ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.myapp.myapplication/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService --es  "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

The response:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.myapp.myapplication/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Now when I run the app I get the `I/GAV3(17797): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.`

Then I tried the custom receiver:
Here is my code:

```
<service android:name="com.myapp.myapplication.ReferrerCatcher"/>
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.myapplication.ReferrerCatcher" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my receiver:

```
package com.myapp.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver; 


public class ReferrerCatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {  

      private static String TAG = "INSTALL_RECEIVER"; 

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Received install event");
            String referrer = "";
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras != null) {
                referrer = extras.getString("referrer");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Referer is: " + intent + " :: " + extras );
            new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent); 
        }
}
```

And this is my test for the custom receiver:
`~/development/sdk/platform-tools $ ./adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.myapp.myapplication/com.myapp.myapplication.ReferrerCatcher --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"`

And this is the response:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.myapp.myapplication/.ReferrerCatcher (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Now when I run the app this is what I get:

```
08-15 14:59:38.391: D/INSTALL_RECEIVER(24996): Referer is: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER flg=0x10 cmp=com.myapp.myapplication/.ReferrerCatcher (has extras) } :: Bundle[{referrer=utm_source=testSource}]
```

Which is better than the last test however I am not getting the full referrer. I am just getting the source. Can you please have a look at the code and see if I am making any mistake? I have been struggling with this code for 2 days now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you resolved above problem, because I've met exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

Short and simple answer. You must **encode** your referrer information or you only get the first param. You can change the order of params and you'll still get the first param value.

```
utm_source%3DtestSource%26utm_medium%3DtestMedium%26utm_term%3DtestTerm%26utm_content%3DtestContent%26utm_campaign%3DtestCampaign
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It has been so long since I have had that issue, that I gave up on it. and I dont have the application anymore to test it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some characters as below:
Change
%26 —> &
%3D —> =