# Android Analytics Correct Receiver Definition

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm setting up Google Analytics on my app and I've been following the Google documentation for v4. When using Campaign Tracking they say to add the following the the Manifest

```
   <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This seems fine but then when I used the shell and logcat with adb to verify all was working I was getting No Campaign Data found. The example data they said to run in the shell with the app closed was

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
            -n com.mystraldesign.colorlib/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver
            --es  "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

Every time this produced the same error `No Campaign Data found`. I started playing around and discovered the receiver name in the Manifest

`com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver`

was different from the test code which used

`com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver`

So I changed the test code to use the same receiver name as the app so it now looks like this

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
            -n com.mystraldesign.colorlib/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver
            --es  "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

This produces the correct logcat output that a campaign message was sent properly.

My question is which is the correct. Should I leave the manifest receiver call as is and assume Google just hasn't updated their example or should I change the manifest to match the example?

Comment: Did you resolved above problem, because I've met exactly the same? I've found a hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321521/broadcasting-an-install-referrer-intent-issue), but I don't think so that refferer information is encoded

Comment: @Specku I never got a proper answer from Google but I deployed the app using the second way (that worked) and it fed back the analytics data just fine.

Comment: thanks, I will play with it a little bit more and try how does it work in standard environment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest v4 Google Analytics SDK provided with Google Play services the correct receiver is com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver. Google Analytics  v2 receiver is using different class - com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver. Check that your app is using Google Analytics from Google Play Service jar and not the standalone Google Analytics v2 SDK.